# Print STDOUT/STDERR and write them to a file in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

Is there a way to have Bash redirect STDOUT/STDERR to a file yet still print them out to the terminal as well?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will redirect both STDOUT and STDERR to the same file:

```
some_command 2>&1 | tee file.log
```

#### Example

```
$ touch foo; ls foo asfdsafsadf 2>&1 | tee file.log
ls: asfdsafsadf: No such file or directory
foo
$ cat file.log
ls: asfdsafsadf: No such file or directory
foo
```

Comment: If you don't want to overwrite `file.log` each time, use `tee -a file.log`

Answer (score 4):

Use the [tee](http://ss64.com/bash/tee.html) command.

```
$ echo "hi" | tee output.txt
hi
[unix]$ ls
output.txt
[unix]$ cat output.txt 
hi
```

Comment: Yup - good call.  @SiegeX had it perfect.  Misread that piece, but that is definitely a good trick to know - I've blogged about it previously.   http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/bash-how-to-redirect-standard-error-to-standard-out/